# JSON и JavaScript

Tags: строки, json, javascript, хранение-данных

вот код [Тык](http://jsfiddle.net/Perkovec/XELkG/)

У меня есть несколько строк JSON (их может быть от 1 до 1000) а имена строк нумируются таким образом: tranz(номер строки)<br>
И я собираюсь циклом их всех выводить но не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так попробуйте:

```
tranz1 = '{ "name" : "blablabla" }';
tranz2 = '{ "name" : "lol lol lol"}';
tranz3 = '{ "name" : "И так далее"}';
for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    var bla = JSON.parse(eval("tranz" + i));
    alert(bla.name);
}
```

Можно конечно `eval("tranz" + i)` заменить на `window["tranz" + i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно программисты пользуются в таком случае массивами, а `eval` вообще стараются избегать.

```
var tranz = {}
tranz[0] = '{ "name" : "blablabla" }';
tranz[1] = '{ "name" : "lol lol lol"}';
tranz[2] = '{ "name" : "И так далее"}';

for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var bla = JSON.parse(tranz[i]);
    alert(bla.name);
}
```

Comment: Зато позволяет решить задачу в том виде в котором она сформулирована.

Comment: А чем eval так плох?

Comment: @Perkovec, 
  
 1. Мешает браузеру оптимизировать код => замедляет его выполнение.
 2. Затрудняет отладку.
 3. При неаккуратном использовании создает дыры в безопасности.

Я не говорю, что им не нужно пользоваться абсолютно никогда. Но в подавляющем большинстве случаев он не нужен.

@Vladislav Pyatkov, иногда бывает так,что задача не очень корректно сформулирована.